# How to Read JSON in Go Lang

Tags: json, go

I have the following JSON array received as a web service output using CURL.

```
{
  "total_rows": 4,
  "offset": 0,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "_design/people",
      "key": "_design/people",
      "value": {
        "rev": "3-d707964c8a3fa0c0c71e51c600bbafb8"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "aamir",
      "key": "aamir",
      "value": {
        "rev": "3-4b9095435470366fb77df1a3d466bcff"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "iyaan",
      "key": "iyaan",
      "value": {
        "rev": "1-4fea2c459d85480bf4841c7e581180c0"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "tahir",
      "key": "tahir",
      "value": {
        "rev": "2-593c9237a96836a98f53c0374902964a"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract the "total_rows" object separately from it and "rows" object separately.

Comment: try "encoding/json" package

Comment: Can you show a snippet of code you've attempted to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You just need the package `encoding/json`.

Defined Row struct:

```
type Row struct {
    Id  string `json:"id"`
    Key string `json:"key"`
    Value struct {
        Rev string `json:"rev"`
    } `json:"value"`
}
```

Defined Data Sturct:

```
type Data struct {
    TotalRows int `json:"total_rows"`
    Offset    int `json:"offest"`
    Rows      []Row `json:"rows"`
}
```

And then use `json.Unmarshal`:

```
b := []byte("json string")
data := Data{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &data); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(data.TotalRows, data.Offset)

for _, row := range data.Rows {
    fmt.Println(row.Id, row.Key)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster suggested, "encoding/json" will set you up with what you need. I will also recommend trying some of the third party libraries as they can maybe better fit your implementation. Initially I would suggest looking at:

- https://github.com/buger/jsonparser
- https://github.com/mailru/easyjson

These are just some quick suggestions and there are other libraries out there. Good luck!